# Unnecessary commas appearing in Python list

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, export-to-csv

For context, I am quite new to Python and programming in general.

I have a list(created with selenium webdriver)that looks perfectly normal, but when I try to export it to a CSV file, every value in the list is interpreted to have a comma-separated between each string value. This causes the CSV file to create a column for every string value inside my list value.

Within the Numbers macOS app, I changed the settings so that the file "separates values using tab." This puts every list-value under one column(Name), but I still see a comma separating every string value in the CSV file.

My rows now look like this:

```
B,o,s,t,o,n
```

But I want it to reflect how it looks in my list on python, which would just be:

```
Boston
```

Here is what I have written in Python for writing the CSV file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv

PATH = "/users/charlesmiele/desktop/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
                        

url = 'https://www.niche.com/colleges/search/best-colleges/?page=1'

clist = []

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
data = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
for value in data:
        print(value.text)
        clist.append(value.text)
time.sleep(1)

with open("list.csv", 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Name'])
        writer.writerows(clist)

driver.quit()
print(clist)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you have in clist?

Comment: What's the value of `clist`?  It sounds like you might have done something like `list("Boston")` (which converts the string into a list of characters) when you meant to do `["Boston"]`.

Comment: Please post more complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this simply with dataframes. It doesn't skip a line in Excel.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(clist,columns=['Name'])
df.to_csv('list.csv', index=False)
```

Import

```
import pandas as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `writerows(rows)`. [Each element in `rows` has to be an iterable (e.g., a list) of strings or numbers.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)

In your `for`-loop, just change `clist.append(value.text)` to `clist.append([value.text])`. This way, each row to be written will consist of a list with just 1 string element.

```
for value in data:
    print(value.text)
    clist.append([value.text])
```